# jQuery: Preserve the values in dynamic textarea's generated on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a multiselect dropdown, on selection textareas are appended in div.

Below is the code :

```
jQuery('#proprtyid').change(function () {
   var texts = document.getElementById("texts");
   var countoptions = jQuery(".propertiesselectbox :selected").length;
   texts.innerHTML = "";
   x=[];
   jQuery(".propertiesselectbox").children(':selected').each(function(){  
      x.push(jQuery(this).text());
   });  
   for(i=0; i < countoptions; i++) {
      texts.innerHTML += '<p style="margin:20px 0 5px 0;">Please add the description for: <b>' + x[i] + '</b></p><textarea style="display: block;margin:0px 0 20px 0;" rows="4" cols="50" name="propnotes_'+ i +'" /></textarea>';
   }
});
```

So the issue is, I made a selection and according to the length through jquery I appended those number of textarea's to the div and added the text in them, now upon making of a new selection all of my previously generated textarea's got removed, which I don't want :(

Is there any way to keep in place those textarea's upon making a new selection?

I have searched and used every example which is available in stack-overflow but none from them help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide html?

Comment: `texts.innerHTML = "";` - this line deletes all content inside the `texts` element. Rather than re-populating the box entirely on each change, perhaps populate the array, compare it to what is already in the `texts` element, and make only the necessary changes.

Comment: While I don't know what is the different between `#proprtyid` select and `.propertiesselectbox` select..But I create a demo .. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

***First of all***  I don't prefer mixing between jquery and pure javascript .. So I'll write my code in jquery

***Second*** if you need my opinion in this .. I can say you choose a hard way to accomplish that .. in a simple way you can 'append()' all the options in `#texts` onload and show/hide them on selection change

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var texts = $("#texts");
    // append divs for each select option
    $("#proprtyid option").each(function(i){  
       var getText = $(this).text();
       texts.append('<div data-option="'+i+'"><p style="margin:20px 0 5px 0;">Please add the description for: <b>' + getText + '</b></p><textarea style="display: block;margin:0px 0 20px 0;" rows="4" cols="50" name="propnotes_'+ i +'" /></textarea></div>');
    });
    // hide all divs
    $('div[data-option]').hide(0);
    // select change event
    $('#proprtyid').change(function () {
       //loop through options
       $(this).find('option').each(function(index){
         if(this.selected){
           $('div[data-option='+ index +']').show(0);
         }else{
           $('div[data-option='+ index +']').hide(0);
         }
       });
    }).change();
});
```

***Working Demo***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var texts = $("#texts");
    // append divs for each select option
    $("#proprtyid option").each(function(i){  
       var getText = $(this).text();
       texts.append('<div data-option="'+i+'"><p style="margin:20px 0 5px 0;">Please add the description for: <b>' + getText + '</b></p><textarea style="display: block;margin:0px 0 20px 0;" rows="4" cols="50" name="propnotes_'+ i +'" /></textarea></div>');
    });
    // hide all divs
    $('div[data-option]').hide(0);
    // select change event
    $('#proprtyid').change(function () {
       //loop through options
       $(this).find('option').each(function(index){
         if(this.selected){
           $('div[data-option='+ index +']').show(0);
         }else{
           $('div[data-option='+ index +']').hide(0);
         }
       });
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="proprtyid" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option selected value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="texts"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to save data from a loop in HTML attribute, 
Instead of

```
for(i=0; i < countoptions; i++) { texts.innerHTML += '<p style="margin:20px 0 5px 0;">Please add the description for: <b>' + x[i] + '</b></p><textarea style="display: block;margin:0px 0 20px 0;" rows="4" cols="50" name="propnotes_'+ i +'" /></textarea>'; }
```

Write

```
var text = "";
for(i=0; i < countoptions; i++) { text += '<p style="margin:20px 0 5px 0;">Please add the description for: <b>' + x[i] + '</b></p><textarea style="display: block;margin:0px 0 20px 0;" rows="4" cols="50" name="propnotes_'+ i +'" /></textarea>'; }
//then after the loop, set the value of your HTML to the **text** variable 
texts.innerHTML = text;
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The call for

```
texts.innerHTML = "";
```

Causes your selections to be cleared out. You will need to avoid it. I do not have your entire html, but this may change based on your logic.